# Prove that the following cohomological map is an isomorphism

Tags: homological-algebra, class-field-theory

Let $A$ be a $G$-module where $G$ is a finite group.
Let $B= A \oplus \mathbb{Z}[G]$. $H^0(H,B)$ is assumed to be cyclic of order $|H| \ \forall H \leq G$. Assume that $a_0+N_GA$ is the generator of $H^0(G,A)$.
Consider the map $f:\mathbb{Z} \to B$, where $f(n)=na_0+nN_G$ where $N_G= \sum _{\sigma \in G} \sigma$. The map is injective. Prove that the induced cohomological map $\tilde{f}: H^0(H,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^0(H,B)$ is an isomorphism.

This appears in a proof of Tate's theorem in Part I, Chapter 7 in Class Field Theory -The Bonn Lectures by Jurgen Neukirch.

We could show either injectivity or surjectivity as both cohomology groups are cyclic of the same order.

I have attempted two proofs in the comments. The first one is incorrect. I believe that the second one is correct. If there is another approach, please let me know

Comment: Let us try to show injectivity. Suppose, $f(n_1)+N_HB=f(n_2)+N_HB$, then, $(n_1-n_2)(a_0+N_G) \in N_HB$. This would mean that $(n_1-n_2)a_0 \in N_HA \subset N_GA$. But that implies that $n_1-n_2$ is divisible by $|H|$. This proves injectivity and thus shows that the map is an isomorphism

Comment: My claim that $N_HA \subset N_GA$ is wrong

Comment: By $H^0() $, do you mean the Tate cohomology groups?

Comment: Yes. I have considered Tate Cohomology

Comment: Let us try to show injectivity. Suppose, $f(n_1)+N_HB=f(n_2)+N_HB$, then, $(n_1−n_2)(a_0+N_G)∈N_HB$. This would mean that $(n_1−n_2)a_0∈N_HA$.  But that implies that n1−n2 is divisible by |H| by considering cor $\circ$ res (a)=(G:H)a. This proves injectivity and thus shows that the map is an isomorphism